# O que significa a expressão "no prelo"?

Tags: expressões

Quero saber o que significa de fato a expressão "no prelo", como e quando devo utiliza-la?

Habitualmente a vejo em citações de artigos, exemplo: De acordo com Silva (2015, no prelo).

Comment: Ouviste esta expressão em que contexto? Podes citar uma frase? [Prelo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/prelo) é a máquina usada para imprimir jornais. Eu sempre ouvi esta expressão como uma notícia que está prestes a ser revelada (pois está no prelo, para sair no jornal).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Prelo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/prelo) é a prensa, a máquina usada para imprimir livros e jornais. No caso específico citado, onde a expressão acompanha um artigo, indica que tal artigo ainda não foi tornado público em versão impressa.

Artigos científicos, que citam outros artigos, costumam ter uma seção *bibliografia* ao final onde são publicados maiores detalhes sobre cada artigo. Normalmente são incluídos o(s) nome(s) do(s) autor(es), o veículo em que foi publicado (anais de uma conferência, livro, journal, etc.) e a data de publicação. Terias como verificar o que é dito sobre tal artigo *no prelo*?

Comment: Na minha opinião, podes tirar o «dá a impressão»: não foi mesmo tornado público. Ou melhor, pode até estar disponível online, mas ainda não saiu em papel; está ainda em impressão, e espera-se que seja publicado em breve. O link na tua resposta inclui «obra no prelo». Muitas revistas científicas disponibilizam os artigos online antes de sair a revista em papel.

Answer (score 2):

Quando dita de artigos científicos, a expressão *no prelo* significa que o artigo citado foi aceito para publicação, mas ainda não está publicado no meio impresso, de sorte que o leitor não teria acesso ao artigo diretamente pelo periódico que o aceitou para publicação. É uma extensão por vias metafóricas do que ocorria antigamente, quando o artigo estava literalmente no prelo.

Hoje em dia, contudo, a maioria dos artigos se disponibilizam por meio digital, o que provavelmente fará com que a expressão "*no prelo*" comece a cair em desuso, uma vez que permite uma ambiguidade: o artigo pode ter sido aceito para publicação e estar em processo de editoração, mas ainda não disponível como *online first*, como também pode estar disponível como *online first*, mas ainda não disponível em uma determinada edição da revista com seus respectivos volume e série. O artigo só estará completamente publicado quando tiver edição com volume e série. Antes disso, ele pode ser citado por seu *Digital Object Identifier* (DOI), mas, embora válida, não seria uma citação completa.

Devido a tais novas possibilidades de citação (além do fato de se poder disponibilizar um *pre-print* do manuscrito "indexado" em arquivos digitais acessíveis pela *web*, quando tal manuscrito foi aceito para publicação mas ainda não foi disponibilizado, o que permite citá-lo como referência bibliográfica no escopo da "*grey literature*"), a expressão *no prelo* torna-se ambígua e talvez desnecessária para artigos digitais (dado que o tempo de editoração entre aceitação e disponibilização *online* tem-se tornado cada vez mais desprezível).

Veja a diferença das duas situações (em formato de citação da APA):

- Aceito, mas apenas disponível como *online first*:

> Bortoloti, R., de Almeida, R. V., de Almeida, J. H., & de Rose, J. C. (2020). A Commentary on the Dynamics of Arbitrarily Applicable Relational Responding Involving Positive Valenced Stimuli and its Implications for the IRAP Research. *The Psychological Record*. https://doi.org/10.1007/s40732-020-00413-2

- Publicação completa:

> Pinto, J. A. R., de Almeida, R. V., & Bortoloti, R. (2020). The Stimulus’ Orienting Function May Play an Important Role in IRAP Performance: Supportive Evidence from an Eye-Tracking Study of Brands. *The Psychological Record, 70*(2), 257–266.

No segundo caso, o DOI:10.1007/s40732-020-00378-2 torna-se desnecessário, enquanto que, no primeiro, ele é imprescindível para a citação, pois o único meio de encontrar a referência é *online*.

Ao meu entender, a abstração metafórica da expressão outrora literal "*no prelo*" permitiria entender o artigo em alguma destas duas possibilidades: ou no primeiro caso acima apresentado, i.e., *online first*, ou antes disso, quando ele ainda apenas foi aceito, mas não há qualquer disponibilização e, portanto, forma de acessá-lo. Neste caso em que o artigo apenas foi aceito e nada mais, não seria correto citá-lo. Parece-me que os autores que ainda nos dias de hoje citam *no prelo* se estão empenhando nesse tipo de atividade; afinal, fosse outro o caso, citariam, ao menos, pelo DOI.

Answer (score 2):

Os Artigos no Prelo são artigos aceites e revistos, e que ainda não foram atribuídos a um número da revista, mas podem ser citados usando os dados:
Autor(es), Título do artigo, Educação, Sociedade & Culturas (data de publicação online), DOI
Quando a versão final do artigo for atribuída a um número da revista a versão no Prelo será removida.
Nota: o processo de edição, paginação e revisão de provas poderão levar a diferenças entre a versão no prelo e a versão final.
DOI: https://doi.org/10.24840/esc.vi